# How to change the font batch uses

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to change the font that batch uses?

(By use I mean change the font for the text that's displayed in the command window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font used is not a property of the Batch file, but of the cmd.exe program. To change it:

- Right click over any MS-DOS icon and select Copy, select a diferent folder, right-click and select Paste; a new MS-DOS icon is created.
- Right click on the new DOS icon and select Properties.
- Select Font tab and choose the desired font.
- Select OK

This way, when you execute this icon the desired font will be used.

If you want to directly execute Batch files with this font from the explorer:

- In the Properties of the icon select Shortcut
- In Target, after the ...\cmd.exe string, add:  /C (that is, space, /C, space)
- Select OK

To run a Batch file with this icon, just drag the Batch file over this icon

Comment: Is there anyway i could do it internally, so that if i wanted to make it into an .exe or otherwise, i could have it change the font from the batch file itself?